# Beamer change frametitle font size just for one slide

Tags: beamer, frame-title

I have a slide with long frame title so I want to make the font size smaller. The others are fine so I don't want to change the default settings.

Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: Can you show us a MWE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `{}` will ensure, that the change is only done for the slides within the `{}`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{normal title}
        abc
    \end{frame} 

{   
    \setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\small}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{extra extra extraextra extra extraextra extra extra extra extra extra long title}
        abc
    \end{frame}         
}

    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{normal title}
        abc
    \end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Samcarter's answer is correct *as long as the `ignorenonframetext` class option is not selected.*  If it is, the `{` and `}` around the slide that was intended to be changed are not noticed.  This means the `\setbeamerfont` command is not localized, and all subsequent slides will have the new (smaller) font size set.

To work around this, make sure there is a group around the slide:

```
\documentclass[ingorenonframetext]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{normal title}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\mode<presentation>{\bgroup}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\small}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{extra extra extraextra extra extraextra extra extra extra extra extra long title}
    abc
\end{frame}         
\mode<presentation>{\egroup}


\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{normal title}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```