# Change frametitle color on overlay

Tags: beamer, overlays, themes

Is there a way to change the base colors of the frame (for example its title) depending on the overlay?

I have read [Beamer: locally change frametitle?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/471683/beamer-locally-change-frametitle) and [Beamer change frametitle font size just for one slide](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309479/beamer-change-frametitle-font-size-just-for-one-slide), but I need something even more local, to take into account overlays.

Apparently, the `frametitle` color needs to be set before the frame starts, and overlays don't exist at this point.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  % Ignored, so no point in setting overlays here
  \setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=black,bg=green}

  % Ideally I would be able to use
  % \only<2>{\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=black,bg=green}}

  \frametitle{%
    \only<1>{Random...}%
    \only<2>{Important!}
  }

  \only<1>{This frame should have the default theme}

  \only<2>{This frame should have a green title background}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the usual way of changing color, font, etc. in the course of the document, and redraw the frame using `\againframe`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}<1>[label=test]
  \frametitle{%
    \only<1>{Random...}%
    \only<2>{Important!}
  }

  \only<1>{This frame should have the default theme}

  \only<2>{This frame should have a green title background}

\end{frame}

{
  \setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=black,bg=green}

  \againframe<2>{test}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]